# Mongoose query find 'string' in object field in array of objects

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

My model looks like this:

```
Collection = new Schema({
 name: {type: String, required: true},
 tags: [String],
 movies: [{_id: false,
          original_title: {type: String}}]
)};
```

I need to alter the following query to use 'req.body' (an array of strings) to not only find a match in the 'tags' array but also find match(es) with the 'original_title' field in the movies array.

```
Collection.find({'tags' : { $in : req.body}}, (err, collections) => {           
            if(err){res.status(400).json(err);}

            if(!collections)
            {
                res.status(404).json({message: 'No collections found'});
            }else{
                res.json(collections);
            }
        }).limit(8);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.collection.find({
    $or: [{
            'tags': {
                $in: req.body
            }
        },
        {
            'original_title': {
                $in: req.body
            }
        }
    ]
}, (err, collections) => {
    if (err) {
        res.status(400).json(err);
    }

    if (!collections) {
        res.status(404).json({
            message: 'No collections found'
        });
    } else {
        res.json(collections);
    }
}).limit(8);
```

Comment: This works, but I'm having problems with case sensitivity. Any idea how to ignore that for the 'original_title' condition?

Comment: I know it can be done for a single string using regex, not sure about an array.
But I still think it's better for you to store and search your values when they are all consistently lower or upper cased.